# Connection reset by peer io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am using WebClient from spring-boot-starter-webflux. I am consistently seeing Connection reset by peer error from reactor netty in production environment. Then reactor netty retries this failed request after few seconds (~10-20 seconds). I am not seeing or unable to reproducible this error in a lower environment. I am unable to identify the root cause of this error, here I provided my ClientHelper implementation and logs of the errors,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ClientResponse;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

public class ClientHelper {

  protected WebClient webClient;

  public <T> T post(Object request, TypeReference typeReference,
                    String uri) {
    try {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
      ClientResponse clientResponse =
              getWebClient()
                      .post()
                      .uri(uri)
                      .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
                      .exchange()
                      .block();
      return prepareResponse(clientResponse, typeReference, objectMapper);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return handleException(e);
    }
  }

  protected <T> T prepareResponse(ClientResponse clientResponse, TypeReference typeReference,
                                  ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws Exception {
    String responseText = clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    if (clientResponse.statusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
      return objectMapper.readValue(responseText, typeReference);
    } else {
      throwNewException("Remote service returned a message with statusCode = "
              + clientResponse.statusCode() + "; response = " + responseText,  null);
      return null;
    }
  }

  protected <T> T handleException(Exception e) {
    throwNewException("Communication error. Cause: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
  }

  protected void throwNewException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    throw new RuntimeException(message, cause);
  }

  public WebClient getWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://app.corp.com/").build();
  }
```

```
2019-10-29 20:56:20,383 DEBUG r.u.Loggers$Slf4JLogger [reactor-http-epoll-8] [] [id: 0x65cf7989, L:/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx - R:app.corp.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:xxx] The connection observed an error, the request will be retried
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

> spring-boot-starter-webflux: 2.1.9.RELEASE,
>   reactor-netty: 0.8.12.RELEASE

Please let me know if there is an issue with this implementation and/or how to triage this issue further.

Comment: I'm having similar issues in my prod environment that really can't consistently recreate in lower environments.  Anything learned about this yet?

Comment: I upgraded to latest spring boot version and added connection time out for Webclient to resolve the issue.

Comment: can u plz share the connection timeout config and spring boot version u used.. bcz I'm facing same issue. thanks

Comment: I've added ReadTimeoutHandler, WriteTimeoutHandler, IdleStateHandler with 10 seconds as timeout config. Spring boot version is 2.1.9.RELEASE.

Answer (score -1):

One reason why you would be seeing this issue in production is because of SSL. Try configuring the SSL timeouts

For example, the settings below are for spring cloud gateway which uses netty:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__tls_ssl.html

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          handshake-timeout-millis: 10000
          close-notify-flush-timeout-millis: 3000
          close-notify-read-timeout-millis: 0
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-[webclient-reactor-netty-customization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-webclient-reactor-netty-customization)

Comment: I have switched to http in few production instances and reproduce the same issue. So SSL is not the root cause of the problem.